How to Automatically Split Overlong Lines in FORTRAN 77 Files Using Python?
Following this question, I'm working with legacy FORTRAN 77 files and need to address an issue where some lines exceed the 72-character limit. I've already developed a Python script that identifies these lines, but I need to edit and split them based on their content automatically. Here's the part of the script that detects long lines:
import sys


def show_long_lines(filename):
    """Display lines from the file longer than 72 characters."""
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
                if len(line) > 72 and line.lstrip()[0] not in "cC*!":
                    print(f"{line_number}: {line}")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found. Please check the file path and try again.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python script.py filename")
    else:
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        show_long_lines(filename)

here are examples of the lines detected by this script:
                WRITE(6,*)' COEFFICIENTS HAVE 20 DIGITS, UROUND=',WORK(1)
             WRITE(6,*)' CURIOUS INPUT FOR IWORK(5,6,7)=',NIND1,NIND2,NIND3
                WRITE (6,*) 'BANDWITH OF "MAS" NOT SMALLER THAN BANDWITH OF
             WRITE(6,*)' HESSENBERG OPTION ONLY FOR EXPLICIT EQUATIONS WITH
      &      JAC,IJAC,MLJAC,MUJAC,JACLAG,MAS,MLMAS,MUMAS,SOLOUT,IOUT,IDID,
                XLAG(1,IL)=ARGLAG(IL,X1,ZL,RPAR,IPAR,PHI,PAST,IPAST,NRDS,
                XLAG(2,IL)=ARGLAG(IL,X2,ZL(N+1),RPAR,IPAR,PHI,PAST,IPAST,NRDS,
                XLAG(3,IL)=ARGLAG(IL,X3,ZL(N2+1),RPAR,IPAR,PHI,PAST,IPAST,NRDS,
                IF (ICOUN(1,IL)+ICOUN(2,IL)+ICOUN(3,IL).GE.1) CALJACL=.TRUE.
      &                      ' WARNING!: ADVANCED ARGUMENTS ARE USED AT X= ',XACT
      &               (13.D0-7.D0*Sqrt(6.D0)+5.D0*(-2.D0+3.D0*Sqrt(6.D0))*S2)
                   FJACL(I1+N,J1+2*N)=FJACL(I1+N,J1+2*N)+AI23H*FMAS(I1,J1)
                   FJACL(I1+2*N,J1+N)=FJACL(I1+2*N,J1+N)+AI32H*FMAS(I1,J1)
                   FJACL(I1+2*N,J1+2*N)=FJACL(I1+2*N,J1+2*N)+AI33H*FMAS(I1,J1)
          IF (ERR.GE.1.D0.OR.((ERR/ERRACC.GE.TCKBP).AND.(.NOT.BPD))) THEN
                   WRITE(6,*) 'Found a BP at ', X, ', decrementing IGRID.'
                         Z2(N-NDIMN+I)=F2(IPAST(NRDS+I))+HE*F2(N-NDIMN+I)
                         Z3(N-NDIMN+I)=F3(IPAST(NRDS+I))+HE*F3(N-NDIMN+I)
                   XL =ARGLAG(ILBP,X+HE,Z2,RPAR,IPAR,PHI,PAST,IPAST,NRDS,
                   XLR=ARGLAG(ILBP,X+HE,Z3,RPAR,IPAR,PHI,PAST,IPAST,NRDS,
      &                     ' WARNING!: SOLUTION DOES NOT EXIST AT X= ',X
      &                     ' WARNING!: SOLUTION IS  NOT UNIQUE AT X= ',X
                   IF (THETA.LE.THET.AND.QT.GE.QUOT1.AND.QT.LE.QUOT2) THEN
    10       THETA=(XLAG-(PAST(IPOS)+PAST(IPOS+IDIF-1)))/PAST(IPOS+IDIF-1)
          YLAGR5=PAST(I)+THETA*(PAST(NRDS+I)+(THETA-C2M1)*(PAST(2*NRDS+I)
                   ALN = ARGLAG(IL,XA,YADV,RPAR,IPAR,PHI,PAST,IPAST,NRDS,

I want to enhance this script to split lines according to the following rules automatically:

If the extra characters after the 72nd column are part of a string (bounded by single/double quotation marks), then split the line precisely at the 72nd character.
If they are part of a comma-separated list of variable names, split the line at the last comma before the 72nd character.
If they are part of an arithmetic expression, split the line at the last arithmetic operator before the 72nd column.

The new/child line should start with an & sign in the 6th column. I don't care for proper indentation, but that would be nice.
I'm seeking guidance on modifying my script to implement these rules. How can I identify these different scenarios (strings, variable lists, arithmetic expressions) and perform the appropriate splits?

There are an awful lot of complexities in this type of work, and I suggest that if you're going to do this robustly you generate (and modify the question to include) rigorous test and validation cases rather than working to those identified in your current project. For example, in [tag:fortran77] (as you have it) all source lines are exactly 72 characters wide, and changes to indentation aren't about "proper" but can change the meaning of source. And to make things worse, F77 allows Hollerith edit descriptors (effectively strings without quote delimiters).

Where you have if len(line) > 72 and line.lstrip()[0] not in "cC*!": it's perhaps worth noting that F77 does not allow ! and such a character in column 1 does not indicate a comment. Further, even comment lines are prohibited from being wider than 72 characters (recall, all F77 source lines are exactly 72 characters wide), so you probably shouldn't exclude these lines if you want strict compilers not to complain.

@francescalus, thanks for your comment. I am using git, so I can always revert the changes and return to previous stable commits if anything goes wrong. Could you provide examples to help me better understand the cases where indentation can change meaning? Also, could you elaborate on the Hollerith edit descriptors? Also, this question is not the only way I want to fix this issue. Another option is to find where the gfrotran flags are cooked and add the missing -ffixed-line-length-120. I will post another question now.

@francescalus, the code base is a mess. They have files written in both FORTRAN 77 and Fortran 90, so I have to account for the commented lines starting with !. Also, for some reason, the compiler doesn't care about comment lines longer than 72 characters. I found these out by trial and error.

This recent question, for example, has Hollerith edit descriptors. Indentation matters only where whitespace is significant: the datum of a character constant and in the H and apostrophe edit descriptors.

@francescalus I don't want this to become an XY-problem kind of question, but apart from the other alternative solution I am working on, how do you suggest that I approach this issue? Is there a reliable way to split the overlong lines, accounting for the most common cases and including the edge cases, such as the one you mentioned?

To be honest, if I had code like this, I'd simply swear under my breath at whoever wrote it and get on with life after adding the relevant compiler flag (as you've found). I'd change whichever bits of code I had specific reason to look at/modify to make standard conforming but otherwise ignore it. If writing a tool to process, in bulk, I'd have to worry not only about those edge cases, but also actual pathological cases and discriminate where the programmer is simply using columns 73 onward for comments. If I truly cared, I'd look for established code linters/prettyfiers/polishers.

@francescalus, well, yeah. FORTRAN 77 used to be the language of choice for scientists, and you probably know it better than I do: academics write garbage code. I have seen it in many FLOSS projects. So swearing is fine; I do it, too!

@francescalus  Ernst Hairer is actually a renowned scientist, and if I'm not mistaken, his son was awarded a Fields medal. But yeah, academics are not trained software engineers. I have seldom seen codes developed in academia finding their way to industry. And to be fair, industry is not a perfect example either. I have seen C# code in my company that I would not touch with a ten-foot pole.

@JonSG I did! I know. I have suffered.

Note that 1) by a widely accepted convention, the .f90 extension does not specify a Fortran revision version, but sources in free-form; 2) As far as I can see there are no free-form sources in the code, all the files are fixed-form; 3) As noted by @Francescalus the exclamation mark ! should not be used in fixed-form sources.

I don't know how many files you have with too long lines, and how many lines overall, but maybe it would simpler to do the job manually...

@PierU, there are probably hundreds, plus I don't have a good editor for FORTRAN 77.

@PierU, although Fortran 77 doesn't allow !, nothing in F90+ prohibits the use of ! in fixed-form source to indicate comments, either in column 1 (to indicate a comment line) or outside column 6. Even fixed-form source can be improved by having a comment at the end of a line.
